# $f(x) =\begin{cases} x, & \text{if $x$ rational} \\ -x, & \text{if $x$ irrational} \end{cases}$, then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ does not exist if $a\neq 0.$

Tags: calculus

Problem:

> Prove that if $f(x) = x$ for rational $x$, and $f(x) = -x$ for irrational $x$, then $\lim_{x\to a} f (x)$ does not exist if  $a\neq 0.$

This is an exercise that appears in Spivak´s book, Calculus.

I understand the problem, however, the solution Spivak gave confused me.

Spivak's answer:

[image]

Intuitively, it is similar to what I had thought, however, there are certain parts that I don´t understand.

If $x \in (min(\frac{a}{2},a - \delta), a+\delta)$ then, certainly, $f(x) > \frac{a}{2}$ for rational $x$ and $f(x) < -\frac{a}{2}$ for irrational $x$ but my doubts arise when he says:

> Since the distance between $\frac{a}{2}$ and $-\frac{a}{2}$ is $a$, this means that we cannot have $|f(x)-l| < a$ for all such $x$, no matter what $l$ is.

Shouldn´t it say that we cannot have $|f(x)-l| < \frac{a}{2}$ ? Furthermore, how can we prove that this last statement is true?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that $|f(x)-l| < \frac{a}{2}\implies |f(x)-l| < a$. Do you see why?

Comment: I think $\frac{a}{2}$ is correct.

Comment: I understand that $|f(x)-l| < \frac{a}{2}\implies |f(x)-l| < a$ but  $|f(x)-l| < a$ doesn't imply $|f(x)-l| < \frac{a}{2}$

Comment: You've got a great book,  Spivak has a wonderfully dry sense of humor and a good solid foundation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it should say that $|f(x) - l| > \dfrac{a}{2}.$

**Edit**
Per the comment of fleablood, immediately following this answer, what *I* intend is that regardless of whether $l$ is non-negative or negative, in any arbitrarily small neighborhood around $(a)$ there will exist at least one value $(x)$ such that $|f(x) - l| > \dfrac{a}{2}.$

To prove this, you have two cases:

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~l \geq 0}$

Then, you can find an irrational $x_0$ arbitrarily close to $a$.

Then, $f(x_0) = -x_0 < \dfrac{-a}{2} \implies |l - f(x_0)| > \dfrac{a}{2}.$

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~l < 0}$

Then, you can find a rational $x_1$ arbitrarily close to $a$.

Then, $f(x_1) = x_1 > \dfrac{a}{2} \implies |l - f(x_1)| > \dfrac{a}{2}.$

---

Therefore, regardless of whether $l \geq 0,$ or $l < 0$, you can always find an element $x$ arbitrarily close to $a$ [in the two cases above, $x_0$ or $x_1$] such that $|f(x) - l| > \dfrac{a}{2}.$

The underlying idea is that both the rational numbers and irrational numbers are *dense* in $\Bbb{R}$, which signifies that given any $a \in \Bbb{R}$, you can find both a rational number and an irrational number arbitrarily close to $(a)$.

Comment: "Yes, it should say that $|f(x)−l|>\frac a2$".  Nitpick.  No it should *not* say that. If $l>0$ there we we will always have some rational $x$ where $|f(x)-l|\le \frac a2$ and if $l\le 0$ there will always have some irrrational where $|f(x)-l|\le \frac a2$. So $|f(x)-l|>\frac a2$ for *all* $x$ in an interval around $a$ is impossible.   ....   What it *should* say is that it is impossible for $|f(x)-1| <\frac a2$ for *all* $x$ in any interval.

Comment: @fleablood Agreed.  Editing placed near the start of the answer.